# IF Function in Mysql and PHP statement with LEAST()

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to get a script to show the min value between 2 columns.  The issue I am having is some rows show N/A or NA for one column so it ignores it.  How can I get it to show the value for that row even if it is NA.

Example

```
Name     | pCst | cCst
______________________
Player 1 |  352 | 392
Player 2 |  NA  | 400
```

So in the above I would want to show 400 for player 2 and 352 for player 1

```
"SELECT LEAST(pCst,cCst) 
AS Cost
FROM users";
```

EDIT:

```
"SELECT name,make,model
                    CASE
                    WHEN pCost IS NULL THEN cCost
                    WHEN cCost IS NULL THEN pCost
                    ELSE LEAST(cCost, pCost)
                    END AS Cost
                    FROM users"
                    ;
```

This does not work using the above example. It works if i remove the name,make,model but if i add them the script does not execute

Comment: Are the columns defined as some sort of text? Would seem they are not numbers if you can store `NA` in a cell!

Comment: Consider using `NULL` the value instead of `"NA"` the string.

Comment: @ladman This is from user submissions and NA is what some submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons NULL was invented. Storing your values as strings complicates things and ends up requiring a bunch of casting:

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN pCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') AND cCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN 0
      WHEN pCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN CAST(cCst AS UNSIGNED) 
      WHEN cCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN CAST(pCst AS UNSIGNED)
      ELSE LEAST(CAST(cCst AS UNSIGNED), CAST(pCst AS UNSIGNED)
   END AS Cost
FROM users
;
```

If you actually want some form of 'NA' when both are 'NA', then more (different) casting is required...

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN pCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') AND cCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN 'NA'
      WHEN pCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN cCst
      WHEN cCst IN ('NA', 'N/A') THEN pCst
      ELSE CAST(LEAST(CAST(cCst AS UNSIGNED), CAST(pCst AS UNSIGNED) AS CHAR)
   END AS Cost
FROM users
;
```

If you used a nullable integer type for the field instead, it would be more simply:

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN pCst IS NULL THEN cCst
      WHEN cCst IS NULL THEN pCst
      ELSE LEAST(pCst, cCst)
   END AS Cost
FROM users
;
```

;

Comment: The 3rd part of your answer seems the most logical.  With this couldnt I just use WHEN pCst = 'N/A' THEN cCst

Comment: That is kind of what the first two do; the problem is that to get LEAST to not treat "2" as greater than "10", the values have to be CAST to integer types, which would then have one part of the CASE returning a different data type than the rest. The second one resolves this by casting the result of LEAST back to a string.

Comment: If you know that only pCst will contain non-numeric strings, the solutions I presented can be simplified. I just wrote them with the idea that either could contain such values.

Comment: Ok thank you .. This worked with a bit of tweaking.  Thanks again sir

Comment: I have one quetion. I am not able to add the Name column to your third answer. When I add it the script breaks. How would I add another column or more if needed? @Uueerdo

Comment: Any additional result fields would be added the same way for any version I supplied. `SELECT Name, CASE ....` should work without issue. Check for typos.

Comment: I edited my question with what I tried and is not working

Comment: It's missing the comma after `model`.

Answer (score 2):

[Uueerdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104224/uueerdo) pointed out this would cast 'NA' as 0, invalidating the answer.

<strike>Just a guess, but you may need to cast the values if they're strings:</strike>

```sql
SELECT LEAST(CAST(pCst AS UNSIGNED), CAST(cCst AS UNSIGNED)) AS Cost
FROM users;
```

Comment: Strings like 'NA' are always going to cast to `0`, so this would end up suppressing the non-NA values on rows that have 'NA'. This would show 0 for Player 2, rather than 400.

Comment: @Uueerdo ah, you're right - my brain was on "max" value.